# Ocelot with multiple Configuration files and Environments

Tags: .net-core, ocelot

Is there any way to use Ocelot with multiple Configuration files and environments like `ocelot.service1.Development.json`?

Unfortunately the documentation seems to be outdated and also it doesn't handle my specific request.
I saw that it is able to have multiple files that will be merged [Documentation](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/configuration.html#merging-configuration-files):

```
ocelot.service1.json
ocelot.service2.json

//Program.cs
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((host, config) => {
        config
            .AddOcelot(host.HostingEnvironment)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

It works but doesn't meet my requirements.

The documentation also describes following setup [Documentation](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/configuration.html#multiple-environments):

```
ocelot.Development.json
ocelot.Staging.json

//Program.cs
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((host, config) => {
        config
            .AddJsonFile("ocelot.{host.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

But this solution also doesn't meet my requirements.

Is there any way how I can combine both ways?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but what is your requirements? Show us what files you have

Comment: I guess I found another solution that fits to my needs. I excluded the config file from project and put it directly on the server. Due to the high number of ReRoutes I wanted to split them into several files. Each of that files should be environment specific.

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with a solution:

I edited the extension method `.AddOcelot(folder, env)`. I've added a new parameter `appNames` which is an array of the names in the files to read from `appName.ocelot.Dev.json` to find the files.

Screenshots:

1. [program.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdXFE.png)
2. [File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dni1P.png)
3. [Modified Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGCel.png)

Comment: Can you edit your post to paste code as _text_? You can then _format_ it as code. This will make it easier for people to read and reference. We like to avoid _screenshots_ of code on Stack Overflow. Thank you in advance.